# Is there a class to convert between .NET data and XML types?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I need to convert .NET data to XML types and viceversa and I wonder if there is any class already on the .NET framework to do it.

**UPDATE**

I want to perform a data type conversion.

Comment: can you clarify: are you trying to convert the per-node data in the XML nodes, or trying to create an object graph based on an XML document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[XmlConvert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.aspx)** class should do it for you.

Answer (score 4):

Well there is the [XMLSerializer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx)

Comment: Or the [`DataContractSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx), for better control.

Comment: I think XmlConvert would be more appropriate for this question, but you might be right.

Comment: I prefer the data contract serialize but it requires more knowledge to use but is defiantly better in non trival situations